# Get the list of students, having grades more than them head student

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table:

[image: table]

STUDENT:

```
| STUDENT_ID  | HEAD_STD_ID  |  STUDENT_NAME   |   GRADE |
```

and i need to select list of student_name having grades more than them head student. I tried several selection with subquery but it does not working. Can you help me?

Comment: *having grades more than them head student.* what do you mean by *them*? Is it a typo? And you mean *the*?

Comment: Hint: Use a self-JOIN

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Join` your table with itself to get the grades of the head students next to each student, then filter out the rows where the head has the greater grade.

```
select u.student_name
from students as u inner join students as v
on u.head_std_id = v.student_id
where u.grade > v.grade;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried self join but I do it wrong and now I understand what do I did wrong.